# How to update ubuntu linux 10.10 to 12.04 or 14.04 using terminal?

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, updates

How can I update my OS Ubuntu Linux 10.10 to 12.04 or 14.04?
I had a problem while installing the others and it was the only
it accepted!I want to update it using terminal because the update
manager can't update it by itself because it doesn't find the version
12.04!
Please help!!!

Comment: What problems did you have with 12.04 and 14.04?

Answer (score 0):

Run 'update-manager -c -d'

But quite honestly, dont bother.  Back up everything  in your home folder,  and do fresh install, believe meits a LOT easier and faster.

Backing up everything is overkill but this method ensures thar NOTHING important to you is missed.
Perform this step even if you were a responsible user and were performing your duties by backing up anyways.

Yeah, you're going to lose some settings,  but their different anyways.